# Magento Cant Update product attribute from magento admin panel

Tags: php, magento, attributes

After editing short description from magento admin panel and clicking on save, it shows message that it was saved successfully, but the short description was same before editing. I hope this issue is because of store view.

Has anyone else experienced this, and, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: please clear the cache in backend system->cachemangment

Answer (score 0):

If you use multiple store view...then on a drop would be came on left of each product view  admin panel and  here you should change  store view according to your respective.after that you would change data of product.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is effect visible in backend.
2. Are you sure you are viewing same store view for edit effect where you edited.In left sode you have an option to select store.
3. If effect visiblein backend and not in front end then you need to clear cache.Also if you are looking intp some listing page you need to do reindexing.